# gcc LTO - shared library - Am I right?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, lto

### Context :

Trying to understand how lto (link time compilation) works

### Code:

I have those files :

julia.h:

```
#ifndef JULIA_H
#define JULIA_H
#include <stdio.h>
int julian();

#endif // JULIA_H
```

julia.c :

```
#include "julia.h"

int julian()
{
    printf("Hello Worldu!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

compiled as a shared library like so :
gcc -O3 -fPIC -shared julia.c -o libjulia.so -L$PWD -I$PWD -flto

and my main program :

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "julia.h"

int main()
{

    julian();

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with :
gcc -O3 main.c -I/path/to/inc -L/path/to/lib -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/lib -ljulia -flto

It compiles fines.

### Question :

So, this is a hello world program but am I doing it right with LTO ?
Is is all it takes to optimize the linkage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LTO doesn't affect shared libraries; they're being linked with by dynamic linker, which is not aware of LTO and can't modify code at runtime.

Moreover, LTO doesn't even work with static libraries, but some day it presumably will (it is TODO on gcc wiki).

But yes, what it takes to enable is using `-flto` on **both** compilation and linking phases.

Comment: So basically, for me it is useless, right ? What optimizations can be made for dynamic libraries ?

Comment: It will affect compilation of library itself, if it consists of multiple files, so it still may have some benefits. Compilation time will suffer severely, of course.

Comment: Ok, So I will use the usual pattern gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o -flto and link that to my main gcc -O3 main.c foo.o L/blah -Iblah -flto. And then I will benefit from all optimizations possible. I hope.

Comment: There are a lot more flags like `-fomit-frame-pointer`, `-ffast-math`, `-mtune`, `-msse` and many many more, but they are not generic or have other problems, - so disabled by default.

Comment: Note that when compiling and linking the dynamic library itself, you can use link time optimization.(Ofcourse, if your dynamic library consists of just 1 file, it's pretty much useless to use LTO). You can use LTO with static libraries, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878407/how-can-i-use-lto-with-static-libraries

Answer (score 15):

<sup>As [keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24734213/938111) saied, *LTO doesn't affect shared libraries*. But...</sup>

## LTO works with static libraries

Just replace `ar` by `gcc-ar` and add the option `--plugin gccpath/liblto_plugin.so`. This LTO plugin will copy the [declarations, types, callgraph and GIMPLE representation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html) from LTO-*compiled* objects into the static lib. (same for `ranlib` to be replaced by `gcc-ranlib`)

### In your example

```
# First retrieve the GCC path
gccpath=$(gcc -print-search-dirs | awk '/install/{print $2}')

# Compile the static library
gcc julia.c -o julia.o -flto -ffat-lto-objects
gcc-ar rcs libjulia.a julia.o --plugin $gccpath/liblto_plugin.so

# Compile & link the executable
gcc main.c libjulia.a -flto -Ofast -march=native
```

Note: `-Ofast` was introduced in GCC-4.6 [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4778930/938111) and includes `-ffast-math`.
Use `-O3` if you don't want that.

### Update `Makefile`

```
GCCPATH = $(shell gcc -print-search-dirs | awk '/install/{print $$2}')
AR      = gcc-ar
RANLIB  = gcc-ranlib
ARFLAGS     += --plugin $(GCCPATH)/liblto_plugin.so
RANLIBFLAGS += --plugin $(GCCPATH)/liblto_plugin.so
CFLAGS      += -flto -ffat-lto-objects
CXXFLAGS    += -flto -ffat-lto-objects
LDFLAGS     += -flto=8    # 8 -> compiles using 8 threads
```

Do not forget, the *real* compilation will be done at link time. Therefore, move your optimization flags from `CFLAGS` (and `CXXFLAGS`) to `LDFLAGS` ;-) One more thing, debugging info and LTO is still experimental in GCC-4.9. GCC-5.0 should improve this point...

Comment: Thanks a lot olibre! Will try that! I did not see those steps in the doc though