# How can I use lto with static libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, lto

When I try to build static libraries with `-flto`, I get undefined reference errors:

**library.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
  std::cout << "Test!" << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
void foo();

int main() {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

**Compilation output**:

```
$ g++ -flto -c library.cpp
$ ar rcs library.a library.o
$ g++ -flto main.cpp library.a
/tmp/ccZIgxCY.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
ccZIgxCY.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It works fine if I link with `library.o` instead of `library.a`.  What am I missing?  This is with GCC 4.9.1 and binutils 2.24.

Comment: Did you try `g++ -flto -lrary main.cpp`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Also broken.  But I found the answer as I was writing the question, it's posted below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer, as I found out from [this](http://hubicka.blogspot.ca/2014/04/linktime-optimization-in-gcc-2-firefox.html) post by GCC developer Honza Hubička, is to use the `gcc-ar` wrapper instead of `ar` by itself:

```
$ gcc-ar rcs library.a library.o
```

This invokes `ar` with the right plugin arguments, in my case were

```
--plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/liblto_plugin.so
```

Comment: It is worth noting that there is also `gcc-ranlib` and `gcc-nm` if you need them.

Comment: @rodrigo Indeed - it seems that `ar` is only part of the picture. I also needed to override with `gcc-ranlib`, as the system default couldn't handle the LTO objects. So, since it seems difficult to find anything approaching a one-liner solution to this: I got LTO working as follows: `./configure --prefix=/opt/testmake AR=gcc-ar RANLIB=gcc-ranlib CXXFLAGS='-O3 -flto'`

Comment: @underscore_d As `man ranlib` states, it's equivalent to `ar s`.  I create all my static libraries with `gcc-ar rcs`, only one step.

Answer (score 6):

As a complimentary answer: with GCC there is also the possibility to use `-ffat-lto-objects` which adds classic object code to the files in the archive. This makes it possible to use the static library in code that you build without -flto.

Comment: The trouble is it's difficult to catch where LTO is failing when fat-objects are used