# Using -flto with autotools

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, autotools

Given a C++ program that uses GNU autotools, what's the easiest way to compile it with `-flto` (link time optimization)? My understanding is that it is customary on Unix for such optimization flags to be specified by the user or packager, not by the programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-10/msg00060.html), the `-flto` flag needs to be passed as a compilation flag and as a linker flag, so:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS="-flto" LDFLAGS="-flto" ...
```

or possibly:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS="-flto" LDFLAGS="-Wc,-flto" ...
```

might work.

Comment: Or alternatively `./configure CXX='g++ -flto -O2'` since *optimizations* should be *same* at *compile* and at *link* time

Comment: That works, thanks! Actually, `CXXFLAGS='-O3 -flto'` seems to suffice.

Comment: Lucky for you that it was that simple! I needed to add a pile of other stuff, as hinted by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878407/how-can-i-use-lto-with-static-libraries#comment67660913_25878408 The final configure command was this: `./configure --prefix=/opt/testmake AR=gcc-ar RANLIB=gcc-ranlib CXXFLAGS='-O3 -flto'`